# Interpretation of Feynman's propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-interpretations, greens-functions, correlation-functions, propagator

What is the interpretation of the Feynman's [propagator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagator)

$$D(x-y) :=\langle 0 |\phi(t,x)\phi(t',y)|0\rangle~?$$

As far as I understand, it is the following. $|D(x-y)|^{2}$ is the probability density of finding a particle at state $\phi(t,x)$ once it was known to be at state $\phi(t',y)|0\rangle$ initially.

Moreover, in the particular case where $\phi(t,x)$ is the Klein-Gordon quantum field, the interpretation of $\phi(t,x)|0\rangle$ is that a particle with state given by a sobreposition of well-defined momentum $|p\rangle$ is created at $(t,x)$. Thus, the first interpretation, in this case, reduces to "the probability density that such a particle created at $(t',y)$ will be found in $(t,x)$".

Are my interpretations correct?

Comment: I've always found this interpretation a little puzzling. The reason is that what allows us to talk about "the probability of a particle to be found at $x$" in non-relativistic QM is the fact that *we have a position operator*. Its (improper) eigenstates $|x\rangle$ then can be projected onto to extract the probability amplitude for the particle to be found near $x$. The issue, however, is that as far as I know, there is no position operator in the relativistic setting, so I don't know how $\phi(t,x)|0\rangle$ is to be interpreted as a "state with a particle at $(t,x)$".

Comment: The charge density at a certain point is certainly an observable. If I remember well, in the scalar case also the field itself is an observable

Comment: @Gold Were you able to find an answer to this? Is it that this propagator describes the probability of a particle, almost localised at $(x,t)$, to become almost localised at $(x',t')$? By almost localised, I mean the Mcdonald's function instead of the delta function

Comment: @RyderRude in the end I just found it better to let go of trying to interpret the position space propagator as an amplitude for a particle to travel from some point in spacetime to some other point. Honestly, I think the only way in which one could possibly back such interpretation would be if there were a position operator, but it is known that in relativistic QFT one does not have such an operator. Besides, it turns out that one actually never needs to invoke such an interpretation, since that is not how the propagator is used in any case.

Comment: @Gold Yeah, in scattering experiments, the propagator is only used for virtual particles. Maybe I should just be satisfied with "shut up and calculate". I still find it very fascinating that the propagator is the path integral of the free particle action. It can't just be a co-incidence that time order vaccuum expectation value of operator fields happens to equal that path integral. Do you know of **any interpretation** at all of the position space propagatot?

Comment: I think it has interpretation, I just don't think the one in terms of amplitude for a particle to travel for $(t,x)$ to $(t',x')$ is accurate (but maybe eventually someone convinces me otherwise). Now whether you write the 2pt function in position space or momentum space is just a matter of how you write it down, it is the same object. In that case, considering it in momentum space, the propagator is closely related to the mass of the particle. In fact as a function of $p^2$ it has a pole at the value of the physical mass of the particle.